# Unable to find explanations about "fanX_div" setting (lm-sensors)

Tags: linux, fan, sensors

I'm creating a configuration file for lm-sensors.
I cannot understand the meaning of "fanX_div" setting and, searching with Google, I'm unable to find any kind of explanations.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Some sensor chips use a clock divisor, so that they can store fan speeds using only 8 bits. The `fanX_div` setting allows this divisor to be set, *on chips that support it*. If your chip reports something like

```
  Case Fan:       0 RPM  (min =  998 RPM, div = 8)  ALARM
  CPU Fan:     2500 RPM  (min = 1500 RPM, div = 4)
```

(with `div` values), it uses a divisor, otherwise it doesn’t. Modern sensor chips use 12 or 16 bits to store the speed, and don’t use (or support) clock divisors.

The [`fan-divisors`](https://github.com/groeck/lm-sensors/blob/master/doc/fan-divisors) document has more details (and instructions on how to determine the correct value if necessary).

Comment: Ok, but changing this setting (for example, from 2 to 4), the fan speed (fanX_input) reported by "sensors" command remains unchanged, while only changes the value of "fanX_min" which is halved.
My chip is "via686a-isa-6000".

Comment: That means your chip doesn’t support a divisor. My answer was misleading, I found the documentation and updated it.